# Call Objective-C method from C++ method

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

Hello I know that this problem was discussed several times, but I have feeling that no other explenation works for me. Maybe it isn't possible but... at the moment I have mm file  it looks like (init methods/ header file) obj-c except few C++ methods (library live555 which I use is written in C++), and I can call C++ methods form obj-c just fine. But when I want call obj-c in c++... then I got error. I know `self` isn't know. But how I can move aroud it? I try with 2-3 tuts but all of them assume that obj-c method isn't called inside that obj-c++ class.

My Obj-C++ class (.mm file)

```
@interface testSender : NSObject{
    @private
    NSMutableArray *_buffors;
}

+(id)voiceSender;
//Function to invoke
-(bool)continueSendBuffer;

@end

@implementation testSender
@synthesize address=_address,port=_port;

UsageEnvironment* env;

+(id)voiceSender{
    return [[self alloc]init];
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self initRTPProt];
        _buffors = [NSMutableArray array];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)initRTPProt{
  //init protocol
}

void afterPlaying(void* clientData); // forward


void afterPlaying(void* /*clientData*/) {
    // We and stream and now I want check if it's some other streams to send so normaly I should call
    [self continueSendBuffer];

}


-(bool)continueSendBuffer{
    if ([_buffors count] == 0) return false;
    NSData *nextBuffer = [_buffors objectAtIndex:0];
    [_buffors removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    [self sendNextBuffer:nextBuffer];

    return true;
}

-(void)sendNextBuffer:(NSData*)buffer{
    // Send next buffer
    /setting sessionState..



    // Start the streaming:
    *env << "Beginning streaming...\n";

    // Method afterPlaying will be called after ther will be nothing to send
    sessionState.sink->startPlaying(*sessionState.source, afterPlaying, NULL);
     env->taskScheduler().doEventLoop();
}

@end
```

At c++ method void `afterPlaying(void*)` when I want use `[self continueSendBuffer]` then I got error `Use of undeclared identifier 'self'`.

---

### Solved

**Chuck** did great job and explain me how Objective-C++ works. [Read it!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20960882/989631) 
Basically you just can't call obj-c method in "c++ method" (I know there are free floating methods) with out passing to them `self` pointer.

I have to modify a bit `startPlaying` call and now in third argument I pass `self` pointer
Also method `afterPlaying` had to been change so now she can use clientData pointer. Throught this I can call `continueSendBuffer`.

**startPlaying**

```
sessionState.sink->startPlaying(*sessionState.source, afterPlaying, (__bridge void*)self);
```

**afterPlaying**

```
void afterPlaying(void* clientData) {
    [(__bridge NXVoiceSender*)clientData continueSendBuffer];
}
```

Comment: Give your C++ implementation file (or at least a "glue" file with pass-through methods) the .mm file name suffix.

Comment: there is no such thing called "Objective C++ method". Do you want C++ method or Objective C method? also why you want `afterPlaying` as C function?

Comment: This is mm file but when I try use [self continueSendBuffer] in afterPlaying.  Use of undeclared identifier 'self'. I will update question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C++ does not unify C++ classes and Objective-C classes. It allows you to mix Objective-C code and C++ code, but the two object models are still completely separate — it basically just uses C++ where C would be used in normal Objective-C. What you're calling "C++ methods" there are actually just free-floating functions, because an Objective-C class definition isn't a special context in C++. They are not methods of the class.

You'll somehow need to keep a pointer to the object in question and get that into the `afterPlaying()` function (and also keep the object alive long enough to be referenced when `afterPlaying()` is called). I'm not familiar with the library, but that `clientData` parameter looks promising.

Comment: Great explanation how Objective-C++ works :) that works.

Answer (score 1):

The type of the second argument of startPlaying is std::function? If so, you can pass a Block instead of C++11 lambda for that as the following with "C++ Language Dialect" to "C++11".

```
__weak testSender *self_ = self;
sessionState.sink->startPlaying(*sessionState.source, ^(void *){
    // We and stream and now I want check if it's some other streams to send so normaly I should call
    [self_ continueSendBuffer];
}, NULL);
```

Comment: In this case second argument of startPlaying is void :(

Comment: No way, you passed afterPlaying to the second argument. It is not void.

Comment: I don't know where to put it so i just leave it here. https://gist.github.com/Dudi00/8292245 hope that will clarify it :)

Comment: So, changing "afterPlayingFunc* afterFunc" to "std::function<void (void *)> afterFunc" might work.